# How to fix : " could not open log-file fit.log: " with Gnuplot 4.6 and AIX 7.2?

Tags: linux, gnuplot, aix

With RedHat and Gnuplot 4.6, I've these data :

```
2019-08-30,384.00,225.3
2019-08-31,394.00,225.3
2019-09-01,406.00,225.3
2019-09-02,424.00,225.3
2019-09-03,439.00,225.29
2019-09-04,454.00,234.34
2019-09-05,484.00,234.34
```

And this script :

```
set title "test"
set terminal png truecolor size 960,720 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/test.png"
set grid
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5

set style line 2 \
    linecolor rgb "red" \
    linetype 1 linewidth 1 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1

set offsets 0.5,0.5,0,0.5
set datafile separator ","
set format y "%g"
set key left
myLabel(n) = sprintf("%g",n)


plot "df_output.txt" using 2:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 1 ,\
'' using 3:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 2 title " Free space ", \
'' using 0:2:(myLabel($2)) w labels offset 0,-0.5 notitle, \
'' using 0:3:(myLabel($3)) w labels offset 0,1 notitle, \
```

The result is :
[image]

I would like to put a trendline on the blue curve, So my script looks like :

```
set title "test"
set terminal png truecolor size 960,720 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/test.png"
set grid
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5

set style line 2 \
    linecolor rgb "red" \
    linetype 1 linewidth 1 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1

set offsets 0.5,0.5,0,0.5
set datafile separator ","
set format y "%g"
set key left
myLabel(n) = sprintf("%g",n)

f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) "df_output.txt" u 0:2 via a,b

plot "df_output.txt" using 2:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 1 ,\
'' using 3:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 2 title " Free space ", \
'' using 0:2:(myLabel($2)) w labels offset 0,-0.5 notitle, \
'' using 0:3:(myLabel($3)) w labels offset 0,1 notitle, \
f(x) w l lc "black" title "trendline"
```

And that works perfectly :
[image]

Without the f function and the same datas, this script works perfectly with AIX 7.2 but with the f function, I've this error in my error_log file :

```
Could not open log-file fit.log:
```

And if I try to generate manually the graph, I've this error :

```
Singular matrix in Invert_RtR
"gnuplot_script.txt", line 25:
```

The line 25 is :

```
fit f(x) "df_output.txt" u 0:2 via a,b
```

Du you have any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Most likely it wants to create a file called 'fit.log' in the current workinv directory. Maybe there is a `fit.log` owned by some other user, or set to read-only.

Comment: What does the gnuplot command `pwd` tell you? You can call it directly from the gnuplot command line or from within your script, put it into the first line. It should show the directory where gnuplot wants to generate the fit.log file. Does it show the expected directory? Can you manually create a file fit.log in this directory or modify it if it already exists? There is the command `set fit logfile` to change the path of the fit.log file.